# How to download a lot of remote files with a few Linux computers?

Tags: linux, shell, download

Suppose I need to download a lot of small files from a remote host by HTTP and I have a list of the URLs to download. Suppose also that the remote host allows only `K` connections to my local network. My local network has `M` computers and I would like to distribute the files across them evenly. All my computers run `Linux`. Now I wonder how to organize the download.

Now I assume that one computer is enough to handle all `K` connections and store all those files in its local file system. Thus I would allocate a computer to "download" files to `M` folders named after `M` local hosts. The local hosts copy (move) files from those folders to their file systems. Does it make sense ? What is the simplest way to implement it ?

Answer (score 1):

Your approach is fine but there is an assumption that all files are of same size and all computers have equal performance.
What happens if one computers is done with it files and other is still half way through? In this case although you have processor available but it will be sitting idle.
But to implement this you will need distributed computing which will be lot more complicated, so i would say if this is one time task or if total time take is not large then your approach shld be fine else you need to evaluate distributed approach.

Comment: I am afraid this is not a "one time task". What distributed approach would you recommend?

Comment: Well, i would still suggest to go for distributed approach only if its must. So here is how i will do it, i will get a webservice running on each machine which can download the file. Now i will run a main program which interacts with all the machine. So lets say i have 10 machines and each machine can download 5 files in one go. Now i will send first request of 5 files to each machine and as each machine responds back with successful download i will send it next request.